# What's the difference between use and extern crate?

Tags: rust

I think that `use` is used to import identifiers into the current scope and `extern crate` is used to declare an external module. But this understanding (maybe wrong) doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone explain why Rust has these two concepts and what are the suitable cases to use them?

Comment: Are you referring to the statement `extern crate foo;`? Crates and modules are separate concepts in Rust, you might want to take a look at ["Basic terminology: Crates and Modules"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha.2/book/crates-and-modules.html) which explains the difference between the two (I personally find the examples below overly verbose though).

Answer (score 204, accepted):

`extern crate foo` indicates that you want to link against an external library and brings the top-level crate name into scope (equivalent to `use foo`). As of Rust 2018, in most cases [you won't need to use `extern crate` anymore](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) because Cargo informs the compiler about what crates are present. (There are [one or two exceptions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#an-exception))

`use bar` is a shorthand for referencing fully-qualified symbols.

Theoretically, the language doesn't *need* `use` — you could always just fully-qualify the names, but typing `std::collections::HashMap.new(...)` would get very tedious! Instead, you can just type `use std::collections::HashMap` once and then `HashMap` will refer to that.

Comment: Without `use`, we couldn't even have `std` as the facade it is. Either we'd have a single monolithic standard library crate, or everyone would be dealing with the fact that `String` is actually `collections::string::String`.

Answer (score 129):

Since Rust 2018 you're only required to add external dependencies to your `Cargo.toml`, so you no longer need to use `extern crate foo`.

`use` works the same as before.

Read more in the [official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html).

Comment: Even if it's not necessary, isn't there a benefit in separating external crates from standard ones? Like `extern crate failure;` but `use std::error::Error`

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg You mean just to clarify which imports are from the standard library and which are external imports? Not to me at least, and I don't think that's recommended either. But I think you should structure your code the way you feel makes to most sense to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "`use` works the same as before", before when? Do you mean `before` as in the other answer?

Comment: @nbro I mean as in before Rust 2018.

Comment: Note that if there is no `editiion = "2018"` (or later) in Cargo.toml, it will default to 2015.